# R: How to select options in online form and download the data

Tags: r, download, html, rcurl

I would like to download discharge data for thousands of rivers from this website: http://ida.water.usgs.gov/ida/available_records.cfm?sn=12340000

I have managed to fill in the blank spaces in the form (start and end time) using

```
library(RCurl)
url1<-"http://ida.water.usgs.gov/ida/available_records.cfm?sn=12340000"
start<-"1990-10-13"
end<-"2007-09-30"
result <- postForm(url1, fromdate=start, todate=end)
```

I get stuck on choosing an option on how to save the data in this piece of the page source code:

```
<select name="rtype">
     <option value="1">Save to file</option>
     <option value="2">Save to compressed file</option>
     <option value="3">Display in browser</option>
</select> <input name="submit1" id="submit1" type="submit" value="Retrieve Data" />
```

**I have three specific questions:**

1. How do I select option 1 or 3?
2. How do I "click" the "Retrieve Data" button?
3. How do I download the data?

I think that downloading the data might be more feasible with option 3 (display in browser).

- Option 1 (Save to file) will bring up the standard dialogue asking me where on my computer to save the file. I don't know how to deal with this dialogue in R.
- Option 3 opens a new webpage with the URL: "http://ida.water.usgs.gov/ida/available_records_process.cfm" (Note the river ID 12340000 is not in this URL). I could save the webpage as a .txt file, but I don't know how to get to this webpage using R.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Frauke